# Start project with an HTML file other than index.html

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I am currently developing a Hybrid App for iPhone using Cordova and Xcode.

It by default creates a file index.html and make it the starting point of my application.

I want to know is there a way we can change this default behaviour and my application start from a page specified by me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give reference of the file from which your application starts in app delegate file .Do following 
1. Create and add your html page in www folder
2. change following code in your appDelegate file

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"yourFile.html";
```